# Manage Database on iphone

Tags: iphone, database

How could I manage Large online database on Iphone? Should I have use other than SQLite3?

Answer (score 0):

If the database is *online* meanig on a server, you can access it via webservices (RESt/JSON for example is a common option ) and not use SQLite at all. 
If you want a local cache of the data, you can use either property lists (XML) or SQLite locally on the device ( both methods can be easily managed with CoreData) .